# The selection $('p').get() length is wrong with preformatted tag

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery right now so i am testing some basic stuff and i am stuck with a little problem.

I have this  - when i click the button it alerts me '4'! What is happening?

```js
var paragrafi;

$(function() {
  paragrafi = $('p').get();
});

function test() {
  alert(paragrafi.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  First paragraph.
</p>

<p>
  <pre>
Second paragraph with some preformatted code.
</pre>
</p>

<p>
  Third paragraph.
</p>

<button onClick="test()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspect your source code when the browser renders it. [Paragraphs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) aren't allowed to contain `<pre>` elements so the browser tries to fix the invalid HTML for you and changes it to:

```
<p>
  First paragraph.
</p>

<p>
  </p><pre>Second paragraph with some preformatted code.
</pre>
<p></p>

<p>
  Third paragraph.
</p>
```

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically
>   close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>`
>   tag.

Hence four paragraphs